# How do I remove python installation and all the packages I installed for a fresh start

Tags: python, macos, terminal, anaconda, homebrew

I installed Python 3.8.8 on my mac with anaconda. I also installed homebrew and mongodb. I added a couple of other things following different kinds of tutorials but now it is a whole mess on my macbook. I want to remove everything and start afresh. The tutorials I have seen do not seem to address my issue, it seems there is no python launcher on my install and most of the commands like : `ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.7 /usr/local/bin/python`do not seem to work. I want a fresh restart. What do I do without loosing my softwares and documents?

Answer (score 0):

The above commands don't work since you installed Python with the Anaconda distribution. So you need to head over to the Anaconda documentation for uninstall instructions https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/#uninstalling-anaconda and I'd recommend using option B: `anaconda-clean`.

Note that an Anaconda installation behaves differently from a standard Python install and that it's worth getting familiar with the basic concepts beforehand.